# remove query string from end of URL using .htaccess

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove string from the end of URL:

For example i have a structure like this:

```
http://sitename.com/category/first-category-name/?post_type=question
http://sitename.com/category/second-category-name/?post_type=question
http://sitename.com/category/...-category-name/?post_type=question
```

I would like to remove `?post_type=question` from the end of URL.

I found a lot of examples on stackoverflow, but no one works for me.

Thank you.

Comment: See how to  Remove a specific part of URL query string using htaccess 
 https://helponnet.com/2021/06/07/remove-specific-query-string-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

it's simple, just use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "post_type=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

If you are going add this to wordpress website, you need add it before any wordpress rules:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

but after

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Make sure there is a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*  /? [R=301,L]
```

Place a `?` at the end to remove the query when present.