# Regex to Remove Query String From .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a blog that I recently migrated from it's original platform into a self-hosted WordPress site. The old platform appended a query string to URLs for mobile views. This doesn't have any connection in the new responsive site, so URLs with those query strings result in 404 errors.

What I need is a regex for my .htaccess that will strip off the query string ?m=1 from a URL. So, for example, "www.example.com/post/?m=1" should rewrite or redirect to "www.example.com/post/"

What I have so far is this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^m=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L]
```

Which does absolutely nothing :)

Suggestions?

Comment: My issue was one of syntax. The correct solution is [here][1]. Note the importance of placement when using this solution in a WordPress site.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071671/remove-query-string-from-end-of-url-url-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the trailing slash in `/post/?m=1`

```
#stip trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^m=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcos. This doesn't have any effect, either.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was one of syntax. The correct solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071671/remove-query-string-from-end-of-url-url-using-htaccess). Note the importance of placement when using this solution in a WordPress site.