# What is URL Morphing?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to pass a variables from one php file to other php file by GET method only without showing in URL.

**for example:** `http://www.mysite/test.php?user_id=1`

Instead of this just need URL should be like `http://www.mysite/test`

How it can be possible?

**Note:** I am aware about `$_SESSION`, `$_POST` but all of them are also will show URL like `test.php`, that I do not need actually..

Comment: you just want to remove the extension?

Comment: So, you want to receive the `user_id=1` somehow, are bent on GET requests, but assume it can be hidden entirely in the URL? Where does this idea come from? Or is this a request for URL rewriting basics?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your purpose:

RewriteEngine                          On

---

RewriteCond                  %{QUERY_STRING}           ^page=1$

---

RewriteRule                         (.*)               $1?                              [R=permanent]

Use this for further reference: [remove query string from end of url URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071671/remove-query-string-from-end-of-url-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: nice answer :) @Object Manipulator

Comment: thank u.. it helps me..