# .htaccess - How to remove an end part of a url?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect the following urls from:

http://example.com/index.php/item123-detail?tmpl=component&format=pdf

to:

http://example.com/index.php/item123-detail

In essence removing the "?tmpl=component&format=pdf" from all urls.

I have tried multiple different examples from other Stack questions without luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This part of URL `?tmpl=component&format=pdf` called `QUERY_STRING` and if you want to remove it from any request you could do several scenarios like putting this code at main directory `.htaccess` this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /$1? [L,R=301]
```

So , by the code above you will be able to remove even request with `?` only.

If you want to match only this query string and keep others , let me know to give you another scenario with another condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`

Ok , to match only this query string , replace the code with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component&format=pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /$1? [L,R=301]
```

And if tmpl & format values not fixed and come only into letters, replace the code with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=([a-zA-Z]+)&format=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /$1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I have come across an issue where I actually do need it to be specific to this query as this now breaks another similar query which uses a ?. Please would you be so kind as to assist once more to match only this query string. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Solution found on another post as follows:

[remove query string from end of url URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071671/remove-query-string-from-end-of-url-url-using-htaccess)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "post_type=" [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]

Comment: this will not match the OP query string , it will match post_type=

Comment: Correct, I altered the OP query string to suit mine - tmpl=